On the $p$-adic valuation of the sum of the first $n$ factorials
This is more a curiosity than anything useful. Consider $n>3$ and define $A(n)= 1!+2!+\cdots+n!$
It seems that if $p$ is the largest prime divisor of $A(n)$, then the $p$-adic valuation of $A(n)$ is 1. I’ve tested several hundred cases on mathematica. This function is a translate of Kurepa’s “left factorial” function, but I haven’t found anything in the literature related to this specific question. Perhaps this has an elementary proof.

The $A(n)$ are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A007489 and there are links to tables of factorizations into primes.

The valuation of the largest prime divisor is 1 with probability of approximately $1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, right? The sum of $\frac1{\sqrt{n!}$ from $n=100$ is approximately $10^{-79}$, so heuristically this seems very likely (of course, these aren't random numbers)
